# Monitoring with OP Manager

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-on-prem, monitoring

I am planning to monitor my whole environment with OP Manager but I am not sure what I should monitor in SharePoint apart from the server hardware and basic services.

Can someone tell me what I should monitor in SharePoint 2010? Are there some best pratices around?

Answer (score 0):

Most important is to monitor some page in SharePoint by verifying specific string exists on the page in order to make sure site is really up.

Monitoring Hardware and Services doesn't really tell the whole picture as there are so many ways SharePoint may be broken while hardware is OK and services are up. Just don't poll the page too often, once a minute should be enough.

Comment: ok so just polling any page would be good enough then.....anything else that I should be monitoring....I have to also mention that I am not a sharepoint admin so even if there is something small that need not be mentioned may be helpful here.... TIA :)

Comment: I'd poll some page, then HD free space on server drives (SP and SQL). Also SP related Windows Services, and SP server Windows Event Log that detects High/Critical errors (you will need to find suitable rules). RAM&CPU might be of interest as well.

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help...I may need some more in the future for the same...right now am just trying to setup everything on the OP Manager.. but I think you have helped the most..Thanks Once Again..